# C# generic type in a base class

Tags: c#, generics, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm writing a system that has a set of protocol buffers (using protobuf-net), I want to define something like this in an abstract class they all inherit off:

```
public byte[] GetBytes()
```

however, the protocol buffer serealiser requires a type argument, is there some efficient way to get the type of the inheriting class?

Example:

```
public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<T /* what goes here? */>(stream, this);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well that was embarrassingly simple ;)

Comment: This will give you the base class for all instances, unless you modify each derived class individually (not sure if that's what you want, or not).  There's a reason protobuf.net added the non generic version using reflection...

Comment: Been there, done that. In front of the author of C# in a Nutshell no less. :P

Comment: (all warm and glowey... people queueing up to answer protobuf-net questions ;-p)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write "T" right?

and then in your class declaration:

```
public class M<T>
```

?

-- Edit

And then when you inherit it:

```
public class Foo : M<Apple>
```

Answer (score 3):

Define your base class as `BaseClass<T>` and then your derived classes replace T with the serializer type `DerivedClass<SerializerType>`.

You can also specify constraints on the type argument e.g.

```
BaseClass<T> where T : SerializerBase
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28VS.80%29.aspx) is a description of the types of constraints you can apply.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via reflection, but protobuf-net did it for you.

Just change your call to:

```
Serializer.NonGeneric.Serialize(stream, this /* Takes an object here */);
```

This works by building the generic method at runtime via reflection.  For details, check the code ([second method here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/NonGeneric.cs)).

Comment: How fast is this? I hear reflection is quite slow and I'm using this to serialize network packets in a game - so unless it's blazingly fast it's not good enough ;)

Comment: Reflection definitely adds some overhead (although probably less than your network packet speed, so it may not matter).  Profile it to tell.  You can edit your classes as mention in Silky's answer, which will give better perf, but would require you to all of your classes you want to serialize generic, just to provide the "T".  That may be fine, but it's not a direct answer to your original question, since it's a change in the full class hierarchy structure.  It can cause issues if you already have another base class, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need anything special here... since protobuf-net respects inheritance. If you have:

```
[ProtoInclude(typeof(Foo), 20)]
[ProtoInclude(typeof(Bar), 21)]
public abstract class MyBase {
    /* other members */

    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<MyBase>(ms, this); // MyBase can be implicit
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
class Foo : MyBase { /* snip */ }
[ProtoContract]
class Bar : MyBase { /* snip */ }
```

then it will work. To serialize the data, it **always starts at the base (contract) type**; so even if you did `Serializer.Serialize<Foo>(stream, obj)` the first thing it will do is detect that it has a base class that is a contract, and switch to `MyBase`. During deserialization it will identify the correct derived (concrete) type and use that, so you can use `Deserialize` with `MyBase` too, and it will construct a `Foo` or `Bar` depending on what the original data was.

Thus the following are largely identical:

```
Serializer.Serialize<BaseType>(dest, obj);
...
BaseType obj = Serializer.Deserialize<BaseType>(source);
```

and

```
Serializer.Serialize<DerivedType>(dest, obj);
...
DerivedType obj = Serializer.Deserialize<DerivedType>(source);
```

The main difference here is how the variables are typed.

Comment: Is this faster/slower than then way I'm currently doing it? Speed is an issue.
I have to say I prefer this way though!

Comment: No faster or slower. It *always* has to get back to the base and work forwards.

Comment: Oh right ok, excellent.
As an aside, would you recommend using protocol buffers for serialising network packets in a game?

Comment: I know of several projects that are doing exactly this; my expertise is **not** game programming, though, so I cannot offer direct advice from experience... but *if it works*...

Comment: It does work very well, protobuf-net is excellent, thankyou very much for creating it :)

Comment: Out of interest, which other projects?